# Find string between two character in whole string

Tags: jquery

I am new in Jquery.I have string like `Dear < EmployeeList >, kindly complete your joining documentation and submit the same to < DepartmentList > latest by < DateCalendar >`

I want to replace "< EmployeeList >" to "ABC".

And same rule is apply for other "< >" .
Whole String is not fixed it could be change like that.

`Dear < EmployeeList >, welcome to < FreeTextCompany > We wish you a long and prosperous association with us.`

So please keep in mind string is not fixed it just a template.

Please help me

I am trying to findout string and replace to my string but able to do that

```
  var start_pos = test_str.indexOf('<') + 1;
            var end_pos = test_str.indexOf('<', start_pos);
            var text_to_get = test_str.substring(start_pos, end_pos)
            $('#MainContent_lblSMSTemplate').text().replace(text_to_get, "");
```

Comment: Please do not give negative voting i am stuck here please help

Comment: Where are you stuck? You don't seem to have started (even looking around for pre-existing solutions).

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
function replaceString(string, replaceObj) {
   for (var key in replaceObj) {
      string = string.replace(new RegExp(key, 'gi'), replaceObj[key]);
   }

   return string;
}

var replaceObject = {
     '< EmployeeList >' : 'ABC',
     '< DepartmentList >' : 'DepHr',
     '< DateCalendar >' : '12march'
};

var string = 'Dear < EmployeeList >, kindly complete your joining documentation and submit the same to < DepartmentList > latest by < DateCalendar >';

var newString = replaceString(string, replaceObject); // ouput will be: Dear ABC, kindly complete your joining documentation and submit the same to ABC latest by ABC
```

Comment: hey i want to replace emplyoee to Abc Department to DepHr and datecalender to 12march.

Comment: Updated answer to fit the requirments

Comment: Here you are take Json but i already mention in my question string is not fixed so i cant not define Key value pair

Comment: @PritiChaturvedi If you are not more clear with your question / example then we cannot help you properly

Comment: @DarkAshelin I am very clear about my question please give me genric solution

Comment: @PritiChaturvedi At first you ask the question as if you want a static text (replace all content to "ABC"), then you say it needs to be dynamic, then you say you want to replace certain static stuff to other static stuff, now you say again you want it dynamic. I honestly don't know what you want atm. This is also probably why you got a downvote. Unclear question.

Comment: @DarkAshelin sorry for inconvenience now you have understand my problem please give me solution

Comment: where does the data to replace the string come from? You can create dynamic json values but the method varies depending on where the data originates from

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution:

```
var textstring = "Dear < EmployeeList >, kindly complete your joining documentation and submit the same to < DepartmentList > latest by < DateCalendar >";

textstring.replace("< EmployeeList >", "ABC");
textstring.replace("< DepartmentList >", "DepHr");
textstring.replace("< DateCalendar >", "12 March");
```

Comment: I believe he's after a regular expression

Comment: @Itay while the question title may look that way, I think he's more looking for variables judging by the actual question. But I can add a regular expression method to my answer too.

Comment: You are assuming javascript. jQuery can be used with plenty of compiled-to-javascript languages

Comment: @JanDvorak Is this written in a different way in jQuery then?

Comment: @DarkAshelin jQuery doesn't give off enough resources to perform this kind of operation - which the asker didn't tell us about.

Comment: Edited answer according to OP's last comment